# How to new an InvocationException in Java?

Tags: java, exception

How could I new an InvocationException in Java ?

InvocationException needs an `ObjectReference` in its constructor, I don't know how to create one.

Comment: have you checked it's api?

Comment: Why? Are you writing reflective code that doesn't already throw `InvocationTargetException` that should do so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean InvocationTargetException?

From the API: **Is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.**

Not sure what you try to achieve, maybe share some code and describe your intentions, however if you want to extend this exception then:

```
package .....;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class SampleException extends InvocationTargetException {
    protected SampleException() {
        super();
    }

    public SampleException(Throwable target) {
        super(target);
    }

    public SampleException(Throwable target, String s) {
        super(target, s);
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getTargetException() {
        return super.getTargetException();
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getCause() {
        return super.getCause();
    }
}
```

Maybe you want to override getTargetException with something specific to your requirement to catch InvocationTargetException and rethrow with your specific exception?

```
try{
  .....
}catch(InvocationTargetException e){
  //Do something with e?
  throw new SampleException(); //Rethrow?
}
```

As I said not much information given.